# Java: Need Help Reading a large file into an array list by paragraph

Tags: java

OK here is my question, I am in an introductory course in Java so I cannot use any advanced code. I am needing to read in a large text file and store each paragraph as an address in an array list.  So I am needing to read in the file and split on the carriage return. What I have so far is posted below. Thanks in advance.

```
    public static void fileReader(String x)throws FileNotFoundException{
        String fileName = (x + ".txt");
        File input= new File(fileName);
        Scanner in =new Scanner(input);
        ArrayList<String> linesInFile = new ArrayList<>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            if ( != '/n'){ //this is where i'm losing it
                String line = in.nextLine();
                linesInFile.add(line);
            }
        }
        in.close();
```

Comment: `if ( != '/n'){ //this is where i'm losing it` what do you check at this line?

Comment: I am looking to see if there is a end of paragraph

Answer (score 4):

If the text file contains paragraphs (doesn't contain any line-breaks within the paragraph), then you don't have to check `"/n"`.

```
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        String line = in.nextLine();
        linesInFile.add(line);
    }
```

This would suffice